# Can't able to plot numerical solutions of same 2nd degree ode with different boundary conditions

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

```
s1 = NDSolve[{(PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], u] x[u])/
 2 + (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0},x, {u, -8, 8}]

s2 = NDSolve[{(PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], u] x[u])/
 2 + (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u] == 0, x[2] == 1, x'[2] == 0},x, {u, -8, 8}]



Plot[Evaluate[{1/2*PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1], u], 
    x[u] /. {s1, s2}}], {u, -8, 8}, PlotRange -> All];
```

Comment: Change `(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[u]` to `x''[u]`

Comment: and remove the ; at the end of the Plot[...]

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `x^\[Prime]\[Prime]` is probably a copy-paste issue. If one directly copy `x''` in `StandardForm` from a notebook to somewhere outside of notebook, it'll be like that. This is not hard to fix, when one paste it back to a notebook, just press Ctrl+Shift+N, then `^\[Prime]\[Prime]` will format correctly.

Comment: Interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try  :

```
s1 = NDSolveValue[{(PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1],u] x[u])/2 + x''[u] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == 0}, x, {u, -8, 8}]
s2 = NDSolveValue[{(PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1],u] x[u])/2 + x''[u] == 0, x[2] == 1, x'[2] == 0},x, {u, -8, 8}]

Plot[{1/2*PDF[NormalDistribution[2, 1],u], s1[u], s2[u]}, {u, -8, 8}]
```

[image]